# Windows API WH_MOUSE hook succeed on VBA userform under Modal mode, but fail under Modeless mode

Tags: vba, winforms, winapi, vb6, hook

(I am not a native English speaker, I use google translate, then modify. If something wrong, forgive my poor English.)

My goal is to make a Userform with scrollbar in MS Word, hoping to scroll with the mouse wheel.

But VBA doesn't offer MouseScroll Event Handler. After searching, I know it can be achieved with WinAPI Hook.

I refer to the examples in “*Subclassing and Hooking with Visual Basic (O'Reilly, 2001)*”. After modification, my code can be **successfully executed with modal Userform**.

But when I open **Userform in Modeless mode**, once the hook is executed, **the entire Windows system will be stuck**, clicking windows of other program didn't respond, and the CPU usage > 80%.

I used Debug.Print to output some text. When I looked at the VBE’s immediate window, the macro was still executing, but it fell into an **infinite loop**.

My code is below:
(I use Win10 64-bit and Office 365 Word 64-bit. 64-bit API declaration is according to the document on [Microsoft's official website](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9970).)

**MouseHook Module code：**

```
Option Explicit

Type POINTAPI
    X As Long
    Y As Long
End Type

Type MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT
    pt As POINTAPI
    hwnd As LongPtr
    wHitTestCode As Long
    dwExtraInfo As LongPtr
End Type

'This structure is just the extension of MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT
Type MOUSEHOOKSTRUCTEX
    structMouseHook As MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT
    mousedata As Long
End Type


Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowsHookExA" ( _
        ByVal idHook As Long, _
        ByVal lpfn As LongPtr, _
        ByVal hmod As LongPtr, _
        ByVal dwThreadId As Long) As LongPtr

Declare PtrSafe Function UnhookWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" ( _
        ByVal hhk As LongPtr) As Long

Declare PtrSafe Function CallNextHookEx Lib "user32" ( _
        ByVal hHook As LongPtr, _
        ByVal nCode As Long, _
        ByVal wParam As LongPtr, _
        lParam As Any) As LongPtr

Declare PtrSafe Function GetCurrentThreadId Lib "kernel32" () As Long


Private Const WH_MOUSE As Long = 7
Private Const HC_ACTION As Long = 0

Public IsHooked As Boolean
Private mhook As LongPtr
Private i As Long


Public Sub SetMouseHook()
    
    If IsHooked Then
        MsgBox "Don't hook the MOUSE twice."
    Else
        'I perform thread-specific Hook
        mhook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE, AddressOf MouseProc, 0, GetCurrentThreadId)
        IsHooked = True
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub RemoveMouseHook()
    Call UnhookWindowsHookEx(mhook)
    IsHooked = False
End Sub


Public Function MouseProc( _
    ByVal uCode As Long, _
    ByVal wParam As LongPtr, _
    lParam As MOUSEHOOKSTRUCTEX) As LongPtr

    If uCode = HC_ACTION Then

        Debug.Print i & "HC_ACTION" & lParam.mousedata: i = i + 1
        
        'To emphasize the keypoint, I omitted some irrelevant code.
        'lParam.mousedata gives you the direction of the mousewheel scrolling.
        '(by positive or negative)

    End If
    
    MouseProc = CallNextHookEx(mhook, uCode, wParam, lParam)

End Function
```

**Userform code:**
(The form has two command buttons, which perform sethook and unhook function.)

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmdHook_Click()
    Call SetMouseHook
End Sub

Private Sub cmdUnHook_Click()
    Call RemoveMouseHook
End Sub

    
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)        
    Call RemoveMouseHook
End Sub
```

How to solve this problem?

If the Modeless Userform cannot use the WH_MOUSE hook, are there any alternatives, like WH_MOUSE_LL hook or VSTO?

Thank you all.

---

**===== Update =====**

**In my final test, I find that ‘WH_MOUSE Hook’, ‘WH_MOUSE_LL Hook’, and ‘Instance Subclassing’ all can work in Modeless VBA Userform.
But you should close the VBE first, and then execute the macro from the Macros dialog box (ALT+F8). (I executed  the macro with VBE opened before.)**

my Subclassing code is below:

**Subclassing Userform code:**

```
Option Explicit

'the Userform name is "frmSubclass"
'it contains 2 cmdButtons and 1 Frame with vertical scrollbar
'click the "SetSubclass Button" to SetSubclass
'click the "UnSubclass Button" to unSubclass

Private Sub cmdSetSubclass_Click()
    Call SetSubclass
End Sub

Private Sub cmdUnSubclass_Click()
    Call unSubclass
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.Frame1.ScrollBars = fmScrollBarsVertical
    Me.Frame1.ScrollHeight = 1000
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    Call unSubclass
End Sub
```

**Subclassing bas Module code：**

```
Option Explicit

'WinAPI function
Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" ( _
        ByVal lpClassName As String, _
        ByVal lpWindowName As String) As LongPtr

Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindow Lib "user32" ( _
        ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, _
        ByVal wCmd As Long) As LongPtr


Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowLongPtr Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowLongPtrA" ( _
        ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, _
        ByVal nIndex As Long, _
        ByVal dwNewLong As LongPtr) As LongPtr

Declare PtrSafe Function CallWindowProc Lib "user32" Alias "CallWindowProcA" ( _
        ByVal lpPrevWndFunc As LongPtr, _
        ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, _
        ByVal Msg As Long, _
        ByVal wParam As LongPtr, _
        ByVal lParam As LongPtr) As LongPtr

'Windows constant
Private Const GW_CHILD As Long = 5
Private Const GWLP_WNDPROC As Long = -4
Private Const WM_MOUSEWHEEL As Long = &H20A

'module-level variables
Private m_OrigWndProc As LongPtr
Private m_hwnd As LongPtr


Public Function SetSubclass() As Boolean
    
    'I want to Subclassing the frame window inside the Main Userform
    'not the Main userform itself
    
    'get hwnd of Main Userform window which classname is "ThunderDFrame" in VBA
    m_hwnd = FindWindow("ThunderDFrame", vbNullString)
    Debug.Print IIf(m_hwnd <> 0, "Find Window: " & Hex$(m_hwnd), "Window not Find")

    'get hwnd of client window of Main Userform
    m_hwnd = GetWindow(m_hwnd, GW_CHILD)
    Debug.Print IIf(m_hwnd <> 0, "Find Window: " & Hex$(m_hwnd), "Window not Find")

    'get hwnd of Frame window
    m_hwnd = GetWindow(m_hwnd, GW_CHILD)
    Debug.Print IIf(m_hwnd <> 0, "Find Window: " & Hex$(m_hwnd), "Window not Find")
    
    'I use spy++ to watch all hwnd values, the 3 values of m_hwnd is correct
    
    
    'set Subclass and store the Original Window Procedure
    If m_OrigWndProc <> 0 Then
        Debug.Print "Already subclassed" 'Do not allow to subclass a 2nd time
    Else
        m_OrigWndProc = SetWindowLongPtr(m_hwnd, GWLP_WNDPROC, AddressOf SubclassWndProc)
        Debug.Print "Subclassing succeed."
    End If

End Function


Public Function unSubclass() As Boolean

    If m_OrigWndProc <> 0 Then
        SetWindowLongPtr m_hwnd, GWLP_WNDPROC, m_OrigWndProc
        m_OrigWndProc = 0
    End If

End Function


Public Function SubclassWndProc( _
    ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, _
    ByVal uMsg As Long, _
    ByVal wParam As LongPtr, _
    ByVal lParam As LongPtr) As LongPtr

    On Error Resume Next

    If uMsg = WM_MOUSEWHEEL Then
                
        'the Userform name is "frmSubclass"
        frmSubclass.Caption = " wParam = " & wParam
        
        'By observing the value of wParam, we can know
        '4287102976 represents scrolling down,7864320 represents scrolling up
        If wParam = 4287102976# Then
            frmSubclass.Frame1.ScrollTop = frmSubclass.Frame1.ScrollTop + 15
        ElseIf wParam = 7864320 Then
            frmSubclass.Frame1.ScrollTop = frmSubclass.Frame1.ScrollTop - 15
        End If

    End If

    'Pass message to the default window procedure
    SubclassWndProc = CallWindowProc(m_OrigWndProc, hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam)
End Function
```

**starting point bas Module code：**

```
Option Explicit

Sub testSubclass()
    frmSubclass.Show vbModeless 'the Userform name is "frmSubclass"
End Sub
```

Comment: If you use VSTO then you can use WinForm or WPF and you want need these API Calls.
(But VSTO is already not state of the art anymore look for ExcelDNA :-))
Anyway - why do you use modeless dialogues? These are more than dangerous.
These API hooks are really old stuff to make things for VBA Userforms possible but if I remember right the most problem is the windows handle of  the ActiveX and modeless seems a bit ambitious. Just 2 Pence from an old VB

Comment: Thanks for reply.

I mainly use Word and rarely use Excel. I searched ExcelDNA, it seems to be a good thing. Too bad there isn’t WordDNA.

The “Quick Parts” of Word is really too bad. You have to click the function block on the Ribbon to see the Building Blocks. Without scrolling, it only display 4 Building Blocks at a time. So I decided to make one to replace it.

I have hundreds of Building Blocks, want to classify them into 20~30 categories, and reside them on the right side to look up and click directly, and edit my Word content at the same time, so I need Modeless Userform. @RedHare

Comment: Is the first sentence a typo, it should be “you won’t need these API Calls”?
I don't understand what you mean by this sentences ("the most problem is the windows handle of the ActiveX and modeless seems a bit ambitious.")
I am a layman of programming, and I don't understand ActiveX. @RedHare

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you were looking for a word solution. Sometimes I'm blind for that. Yes, it is a pity, that there is no WordDna. Again, sorry.

Comment: It could matter with VBA Modeless Userform. I cannot reproduce using a Win32 desktop application. You can use [CreateDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createdialogw) in your VBA application to verify.

Comment: It could be [Message Deadlocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-messages-and-message-queues#message-deadlocks). **VBE** 
which is attached to the application queue yields control while processing captured messages.

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT Thanks for your reply. The ‘CreateDialog’ you mentioned earlier, because there is no book to refer to, and it seems that it can’t use the VBA Build-in Userform syntax, so I did not test it first.

As for your new ‘Message Deadlocks’, to be honest, I can't understand what the article is talking about at my current level. It’s the first time I contact with Windows API and the mechanism of Windows message.
Now the problem is solved, but still thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

The book you mentioned is called "Subclassing and Hooking". You tried "Hooking" when in fact your problem is more suited to "Subclassing" instead.

You should subclass your Userform where you want to process the "WM_MOUSEWHEEL" message. Look into "SetWindowLong" and "CallWindowProc" functions to achieve this goal.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Because I am relatively familiar with Hooks at this stage, so I tried this technology first. I have found that WH_MOUSE_LL Hook can work in both Modeless and Modal modes. I will find time to test the subclassing you mentioned.

Comment: I tested subclassing and unfortunately it works fine in modal mode, but also crashes in modeless mode.

Comment: If you posted your subclassing code then I could look at it and maybe see why it's crashing...

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have posted my Subclassing code.

Answer (score 1):

I just solved the exact same problem in my repository [VBA-UserForm-MouseScroll](https://github.com/cristianbuse/VBA-UserForm-MouseScroll).

Basically, I am now able to use a hook with WH_MOUSE for both Modal and Modeless forms without any subclassing. The repo supported Modal for years but only recently I've figured out that in order for the application to be responsive, I must allow time to process display changes and thus introduced a `DoEvents` call. However, this required to unhook before and hook back after. Works really nice. The mouse data processing is done asyncronously via an Object's Terminate event.

Also, in order to allow debugging on x64 where breakpoints would cause a crash, I am now redirecting the delegate (AddressOf) via a fake one which fixes the stack frame.